# How to store a command line arguments in an array

Tags: tcl, expect

How to store a command line arguments in an array in tcl?

I'm trying to store command line arguments (argv) in an array. Is argv is not array? I tried the following code but doesn't work for me.

```
proc auto args {
    global argv
    set ifname [lindex $argv 0]
    puts "***********$ifname"
    puts "$argv(2)"
    for { set index 1} { $index < [array size argv ] } { incr index } {
       puts "argv($index) : $argv($index)"
    }
}
#Calling Script with arguments
auto {*}$argv
```

Comment: In Tcl terms, argv is a list not an array, so you would use lindex to access its  elements and llength to find its size.

Comment: Note that in tcl, the word `array` does not mean array in other languages. Are you sure you want an array and not a list? Even if you're sure you want a key->value pair data structure, are you sure you want an array and not a dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl's `argv` global is a list, not an array, because order matters and lists are an entirely reasonable way of doing the arguments. That's why you use `lindex` (and other list operations) with it. You can convert to an array, but most code will end up “surprised” by that. As such, it's better to use a different array name for that (“`arguments`” below):

```
proc argumentsToArray {} {
    global argv arguments
    set idx 0
    unset -nocomplain arguments; # Just in case there was a defined variable before
    array set arguments {};      # Just in case there are no arguments at all
    foreach arg $argv {
        set arguments($idx) $arg
        incr idx
    }
}

argumentsToArray
puts "First argument was $argument(0) and second was $argument(1)"
```